# How to create Polynomial Trajectories of Linear/Affine Systems in Python? i.e Time varying A and B Matrices

Tags: drake

I am trying to create a Trajectory of a linear system for use in TrajectoryAffineSystem. But I am not able to understand the type of NumPy arrays needed for this.

For a simple Pendulum system, the state trajectory is a 2xN NumPy array where row 1 is theta, row 2 is theta_dot, and column k is the state at time t[k]. This NumPy array is clear/easy to create. Similarly, systems with a 1-D state vector are easy to create. However, this is not as clear when the state matrix itself is a 2D matrix.

For a linear pendulum system, the A matrix is a 2x2 matrix and A[k] is the (linearized) state at t[k]. Which type of NumPy array should then be used for representing this A[0-N]? Is it 2x2xN or Nx2x2 or another way of representing the time-varying linear dynamics that can be used to create an object of the Trajectory class?

Reproduction of the problem on google colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/vyas-shubham/DrakeTests/blob/main/LinearSystems/LinearSystemPolynomial.ipynb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a numpy array directly into the `TrajectoryAffineSystem` constructor.  Those constructors need a trajectory object, for instance a `PiecewisePolynomial` [see here](https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.trajectories.html#pydrake.trajectories.PiecewisePolynomial).  There are a number of static methods on `PiecewisePolynomial`, like `FirstOrderHold`, that will provide the semantics you need to go from a list of A matrices into a trajectory.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying. I think I didn't communicate well in the question that I am unable to make a `PiecewisePolynomial` for time-varying 2D matrices (system dynamics) in Python. A notebook containing various attempts at doing so can be seen in colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/github/vyas-shubham/DrakeTests/blob/main/LinearSystems/LinearSystemPolynomial.ipynb). It seems to be easy with 1D time varying arrays but 2D is not yet working for me.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example of using multiple A matrices with `FirstOrderHold` method? I have tried various methods over the weekend but can't seem to get multiple A matrices to work. Only singular A matrix works until now. The unit tests on github also use only a single A matrix.

Comment: That helps.  Now I understand, and can confirm that it's a limitation in our current bindings.  I've opened an issue (which includes a prototype of the bindings that works for your specific case) here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/15427

Comment: FTR -- the python bindings for ZeroOrderHold have landed, and the rest of them are now under review at https://github.com/robotlocomotion/drake/pull/15442.

Comment: Thanks! I already was able to compile with the changes from your initial PR and test out the new bindings. They work well! I will update my local Drake installation with this new PR and re-compile to get the new version working. Thank you for your help!